# Getting the X posts BEFORE the last 5 using query_posts

Tags: wordpress

This is almost certainly more simple than I assume it to be, but I'm beating my head against the wall here... I've got the following code that simply grabs the most recent 5 posts. What I'd like to do is create an archive that shows the X number of posts that were posted BEFORE the last 5, but I'm having some trouble coming up with the right query_posts variables to do it. Is there any simple way to do this... or should I just skip the first 5 posts that query_posts returns? that seems like the simple way but I thought this might be an opportunity to learn something about query_posts...

```
query_posts(array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_status' => 'publish'          
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the 'offset' function - see this post:

[Wordpress get range of posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219388/wordpress-get-range-of-posts)