# Wordpress get range of posts

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Using wp_query, how can I get a range of posts? When I select a category, I want to get the first until 6th post, then on the same page I want to get the 7th until the 13th post.

It would be easy if I could do this using a normal query.

Comment: `query_posts( 'posts_per_page=6' ); ` - `??`

Comment: I was looking for offset, but thx

Answer (score 4):

Ok,I found the answer. I was looking for 'wp_query range' and didn't find anything, but then I started looking at 'offset' and found plenty information. Didn't think of that sooner.

For anyone else looking for [range](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters):

```
$termId = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();

$args = array(
  'cat' => $termId,
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'posts_per_page' => 6,
  'offset' => 6
);

$category_posts = new WP_Query($args);
if($category_posts->have_posts()) :  while($category_posts->have_posts()) :  $category_posts->the_post();
```

Comment: true, but it took me a while to make the brainswitch from looking for 'range' which is kind of a query thinking, to 'offset'. So I think other people might be looking for 'range' as well ?

Comment: Then after accepting yourself you might want to change the question´s title of the question to offset..

Comment: I would keep it at 'range' for people who are looking for wordpress range, otherwise the post would have no use, right ?

Comment: I looked for a "range" although I know "offset" before. So, keeping "range" is a good choice.